# ionic serve stop after 'build dev started'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

when I run ionic serve, why the process stop at `build dev started`?

[image]

can anyone help me to fix this issue?

I have 2 projects the first project is successfully running and I close the command prompt, when I moved and running to the second project the problem has occured.

Comment: You should post your error in [forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/). It is a better place for these errors like this.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to another live server is running background. You need to kill that server and after that run `ionic serve` again for the new project. Closing the command prompt won't work here. But if you use the `VS code`, then closing the project will be killed the live server too.

Comment: I was tried to kill the server but it didn't works @Sampath

Answer (score 2):

In order to have 2 dev process running at the sime time you need to specify different ports:

`Project1 --> ionic serve --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703`

`Project2 --> ionic serve --port 8200 --livereload-port 36729 --dev-logger-port 54703`

Comment: the problem has occured not only when I run ionic serve, when I run ionic start and then the command prompt showing the option, and I let it for 5 second the command line back to the C:\Users\ninda> @Vanojx1

Answer (score 0):

I've checked and there's no other server listening on that port.

- Restarting my computer sometime works ...
- Now, I disabled `livereload` and just refresh the page myself, it seems to work
  `ionic serve --no-open --no-livereload` ... but I'm sure it's also temporary ...

Don't know what's going on with the cli ...